# Which 2D domain with fixed area has the lowest laplacian eigenvalue?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, laplacian, eigenfunctions, decreasing-rearrangements

> Which 2D domain with fixed area has the lowest laplacian eigenvalue?

I know that a disc has the lowest laplacian eigenvalue among domains with fixed area. But how do I prove it?

Comment: Are you only considering domains with a fixed area? Otherwise you can scale the disc (or any other domain) to change the first eigenvalue.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how does one turn a domain into an eigenvalue?  What does the eigenvalue represent in terms of the domain?  This is to help me (and others) understand the background to your question... with the hope of being able to help you anwer the question.

Comment: @TravisJ See [Dirichlet eigenvalue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eigenvalue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement (for the Dirichlet boundary condition) is known as the [Rayleigh–Faber–Krahn inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93Faber%E2%80%93Krahn_inequality), proved independently by Faber and Krahn about 30 years after Lord Rayleigh conjectured it. So you shouldn't expect to just sit down and prove it on your own.

The [EoM article](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Rayleigh%E2%80%93Faber%E2%80%93Krahn_inequality) is quite detailed. I'll summarize the main points of the proof:

1. The lowest eigenvalue is the infimum of the ratio $\int |\nabla u|^2\big/\int u^2$ over $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$.
2. The *symmetric decreasing rearrangement* of $u$ preserves $L^2$ norm (this is easy).
3. The symmetric decreasing rearrangement of $u$ does not increase the $L^2$ norm of the gradient (this is hard, and is the main point of the proof).
4. Combining 1-3, the statement follows since for any eligible function on $\Omega$ there is another one on the disk whose ratio $\int |\nabla u|^2\big/\int u^2$ is not greater.

Standard references:

- C. Bandle, "Isoperimetric inequalities and applications"
- G. Pólya, G. Szegő, "Isoperimetric inequalities in mathematical physics"